# pyspark join two rdds and flatten the results

Tags: pyspark, rdd

Environment is pyspark, Spark Version 2.2.

We have two rdds `test1` and `test2`, below are sample data

```python
test1 = [('a', 20), ('b', 10), ('c', 2)]
test2 = [('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

Now we want to generate `output1` as below, any help is appreciated.

```python
[('a', 20, 2), ('b', 10, 3)]
```

Comment: Are you looking to get the number of occurrences or just do a join between the two `rdd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a simple `join` followed by a call to `map` to flatten the values.

```python
test1.join(test2).map(lambda (key, values): (key,) + values).collect()
#[('a', 20, 2), ('b', 10, 3)]
```

---

To explain, the result of the `join` is the following:

```python
test1.join(test2).collect()
#[('a', (20, 2)), ('b', (10, 3))]
```

This is almost the desired output, but you want to flatten the results. We can accomplish this by calling `map` and returning a new `tuple` with the desired format. The syntax `(key,)` will create a one element tuple with just the key, which we add to the values.

You can also use the DataFrame API, by using [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF) to convert your RDDs to DataFrames:

```python
test1.toDF(["key", "value1"]).join(test2.toDF(["key", "value2"]), on="key").show()
#+---+------+------+
#|key|value1|value2|
#+---+------+------+
#|  b|    10|     3|
#|  a|    20|     2|
#+---+------+------+
```

Comment: But, what about 'c'?

Comment: @Prazy this is an inner join. There is no `'c'` in `test2`.

Comment: Oh, yea. :) Good one bro.